# How to deploy Python Celery worker on EC2 (current error 111: Connection refused)?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery

Technologies: Python, Django, AWS, RabbitMQ on AWS, Celery

I currently have my company's website deployed on an EC2 instance. Everything works well, my current tasks is to run a Celery worker but every time I attempt to do so I get the 111:Connection refused error.

Celery runs, RabbitMQ is running but my assumption is that I can possibly not have the correct setup since I have everything within their correct VPCs and security groups.

FILES:

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqps://<username>:<password>@<awspath>.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:5671'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = env("CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE", default="default")
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
   "region": env("AWS_REGION", default="us-west-2"),
}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
```

procfile

```
celery: celery -A bsw_site worker -l INFO
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

error log

```
2022/10/20 20:57:13 [error] 4189#4189: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.176.11.163, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "<company_website_link>", referrer: "<company_website_link>"
```

nginx_conf.conf

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    200000;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
    proxy_read_timeout 7200;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        client_max_body_size  50M;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
I can provide more information.

Comment: Could you please explain how celery and nginx are connected/related? Celery is used for background tasks and not an application server serving django apps to nginx

Comment: @JanMalte I added the nginx file as well because it was brought up to my attention that I may need to add configurations in nginx to allow Celery to connect to RabbitMQ's url.